# how to add offset and limit to my php rss parser?

Tags: php

how to add an offset and limit to my PHP rss parser that returns the result as an object ?, here is what i have at the moment. it doesn't have any offset nor limit, how to approach this ?

```
    class Rss
{
     /*
     *@access public
     *@params url,int ''=default,int ''=default
     *@usage input url,offset and limit,
     *@returns content based onf the offset/limit input
     */
    public function getFeed($url,$offset='',$limit=''){
        $object = array();
        $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
      foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
          $object[] = $item->title;
          $object[] = $item->description;
          $object[] = $item->link;
      }
     return $object;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way

```
$limit = 10; $offset = 5; 
$i=0; $taken=0;
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
    if ($i>=$offset && $taken<$limit){
        ++$taken;
        $object[] = $item->title;
        $object[] = $item->description;
        $object[] = $item->link;
    }
    //little optimization here
    if ($taken == $limit)
        break;
    ++$i;
}
```

Of course you can store `$limit` and `$offset` as object properties, or get them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

how about a single counter thing? set offset/limit as needed

```
public function getFeed($url,$offset='',$limit=''){
    $object = array();
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $offset = 3; $limit = 8; $counter = 0;
  foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
      $counter++;
      if ($counter > $offset && $counter < $limit) {
        $object[] = $item->title;
        $object[] = $item->description;
        $object[] = $item->link;
      }
  }
 return $object;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). This way you don't have to traverse all items just for counting things.

```
  public function getFeed($url, $offset = 1, $limit = -1){
    $object = array();
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $limitCriteria = '';
    if ($limit > 0) {
      $limitCriteria = 'and position() <= ' . ((int)$offset + (int)$limit + 1);
    }

    foreach($rss->xpath(sprintf('//item[position() >= %s %s]', (int)$offset, $limitCriteria)) as $item){
      $object[] = $item->title;
      $object[] = $item->description;
      $object[] = $item->link;
    }

    return $object;
  }
```